# How set PATH for all users in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, bash

I have a Debian Lenny server, and I would like the `www-data` user to have `/usr/local/zend/bin` in its PATH, so it can execute a script in cron as `www-data`.

How do I add `/usr/local/zend/bin` to PATH, so `www-data` can execuate files in `/usr/local/zend/bin` ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The first place where PATH is set is `/etc/login.defs`. There's a setting for root and a setting for everyone else.

Another place where you can define environment variables is `/etc/environment`. These settings will apply to everyone (you can't write arbitrary shell code there).

A third place where you can define environment variables is `/etc/profile`. There you can write arbitrary shell code. If you want a user-specific setting, there is the corresponding per-user file `~www-data/.profile`.  But this will only apply to console interactive logins; in particular it won't apply to cron jobs unless they explicitly source `/etc/profile`.

If you only need that `PATH` setting in a user crontab, you can write it at the beginning of the crontab. Note that you need the full list (`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/zend/bin`), you can't use a variable substitution (`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin` won't work there).

Comment: ----how do you reload e.g. /etc/login.defs?

Comment: @MrCalvin By logging in.

Comment: Is there any reasons `/etc/login.defs` would be ignored? I've updated `ENV_PATH` and am echoing $PATH when .bashrc is loaded. Somewhere in the middle it's either being changed, or it's not updated as it's displaying the old value. I've restarted the computer - so it's not that.

Comment: @Annan Chances are that it's being changed somewhere. Do note that my answer was written in 2010, before systemd; if your system uses systemd, it may have its own way to define `PATH` in addition or in replacement of other ways.

Comment: @AnnanFay: I think that depends on the distro you use. I noticed that on Debian 11, /etc/login.defs would be completely overridden by /etc/profile – at least for Bash and any other shell that utilize /etc/profile.

Answer (score 9):

To set a path for all users except root, edit `/etc/profile` or `/etc/enviroment`. For root or an individual user edit their `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in their home directories, respectively. Add the `PATH=$PATH:/new/location/`.

Answer (score 2):

To simply set var for all users while not burden your `profile`, you can add your own small script in `/etc/profile.d` directory like that:

`echo 'PATH="/usr/local/zend/bin:$PATH"' > /etc/profile.d/zend_path.sh`

Then relogin.